# Why does my table border show up in Firefox and Chrome but not Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have some basic CSS on a table and I cannot get a border to display in IE6, IE7, or IE8. The border shows up in Chrome and Firefox. Here's the CSS:

```
#infoTable { width:500px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   border-width:thin !important;
   border-style:solid !important; }
#infoTable td { max-width:150px;
   padding-left:5px; 
   padding-right:5px;
   font-size: 10px;
   padding-bottom:15px; 
   border-collapse:collapse; 
   border-width:thin !important; 
   border-style:solid !important; }
```

In my multiple attempts to get this to work, I added the !important tags to try to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Eric R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use of border-color property

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something stupid. I had forgotten about border-color.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a `border-color` as well.

*Edit:*

Though, to be honest, I placed a table with the same styles as you provided in a plain HTML file, and a faint gray border showed up just fine in IE7.